# Cutting part of a text driven from DB at certain character point?

Tags: php

OK, I have this (parts of an) articles driven from DB. This query grabs small parts of a news driven as a teasers for website visitors to read news nothing else.

Problem of this issue is a word breakup (in some or many cases). Examples:

```
//$DBdata = 'In this case, customers have been asking to develop something.';    
//$DBdata = 'During certain expertize experts were those who were expertized lol.';    

$rsql = "SELECT *, SUBSTRING(a.article, 1, 10) AS article..
$rsql['article'] = 'In this ca';
$rsql['article'] = 'During cer';
```

I get this from DB, of course: **"In this ca"** or **"During cer"**.

But I wish to echo - **"In this"** or **"During"** instead.

So how to resolve this via PHP? To go backtrack until first empty space and to echo that, no matter xy word length in characters?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in the last paragraph, one solution would be identifying the last white space character within your string results. This can be done easily with `strrpos()`.

```
$pos = strrpos($rsql['article'],' ');

if ($pos !== false) {
    $cleanStr = substr($rsql['article'],0,$pos);
} else {
    // String contains no white space - decide what to do then here...
}
```

Comment: Thx matthias just await a min or so to accept answer. Thx!!

Comment: You're welcome. Also take into consideration that pure SQL solutions are possible like explained in other answers. But feel free to also give an upvote for my answer if it suits your needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with pure MySQL using [SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [LOCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate). Use locate to find the space (with a defined offset so it doens't find the first one, 25 for example) and use the returned value in the SUBSTRING.

Comment: But question was how to solve this using PHP, right?

Comment: @matthias I am aware, but as the poster originally tried with SQL it's possible he's not aware it can be done with pure SQL. Pure SQL will also likely be faster than processing it with PHP.

Comment: Agree! But you never know what the reasons for not utilizing SQL in specific cases might be...

Comment: Thx 4 your answer Ashely. I'm aware of MySql possibility - that is why I posted MySQL query code (what was "irrelevant") at first place if PHP would be complicated. Anyway, I implemented matthias solution because MYSQL in this/my case is already overloaded. Website is packed with news and complicated MySQL queries. Thx to all 3 of you for your answers :P

Answer (score 0):

try this one bro..

`SELECT *,LEFT(SUBSTR(a.article,1,10), (LENGTH(SUBSTR(a.article,1,10)) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTR(a.article,1,10)))+1)) FROM table your_conditions`

this gives you a result from the sql Query, you not need to put condition on the PHP side.